# ssrs date param

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, reporting-services, parameters

I have a SQL query for an SSRS report to return results where record was created between 2 dates, I am using parameters as for the date values

```
select * from results
where [startdate] >=@datestart or [startdate] <=@dateend
```

when I run the SSRS report and select the same date for @startdate and @enddate I get 2 records returned which I know is incorrect. when I run the SQL query and use a date eg '01 feb 2019' rather than the parameter I get different results. Do I need to exclude time from my parameters or set the time for @startdate to be 00:00:00 and set @dateend to be 23:59:59 to get the same results if I was using an actual date?

Comment: i've added SQL server tag because SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) was mentioned

Comment: That `or` in your script should really be an `and` by the way...

Comment: Yes, you need to either exclude the time portion from the parameter values passed or do that in the T-SQL statement. Also, I think you probably want `AND` instead of `OR` here. When the underlying column includes a time, it is best to specify an inclusive start date and exclusive end date, such as `WHERE [startdate] >=@datestart AND [startdate] < DATEADD(day, 1, @dateend)`.

Answer (score 1):

If your SSRS parameters are `date` values and your data is `datetime` values the easiest solution is to add one day to your `@dateend` and then look for any `datetime` value before *but not equal to* it.

Using a `<` instead of a `<=` is important because time is infinite.  In your example of changing the `@enddate` value to have `23:59:59` appended, any `datetime` values between `23:59:59` and the end of the day (such as `23:59:59.5`) will not be included.

As such, you could structure you script like this:

```
select *
from results
where [startdate] >= @datestart
    and [startdate] < dateadd(day,1,@dateend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should truncate datetime to date only.

```
select * from results
  where cast(startdate As Date) >= @datestart
    and cast(startdate As Date) <= @dateend
```

Comment: This is not valid T-SQL syntax

Comment: The question is tagged `SQL-Server`

Comment: @iamdave Try this one

    "select * from results where cast(startdate As Date) >=@datestart and cast(startdate As Date) <=@dateend".

Answer (score 0):

@imadave's solution will work perfectly.

Also, you could just use the "BETWEEN" clause to get the result. It will return all dates between the given range (inclusive). When the time part is unspecified, it defaults to 12:00 A.M.

```
SELECT * FROM results 
WHERE [startdate] BETWEEN @datestart AND @dateend
```